# How to get the text under the tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the text under the tag
[image]

I tried several different options:

```
dneyot=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]/text()")
dneyot=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]/b[1]/text()")
```

my piece of code:

```
dneyot=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]/text()")
for spisok in dneyot:
    print("Период показов >3 дней", spisok.text)
```

UPD:
I find the items I need in the browser using :

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]/text()[1]
```

but get error

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException:
Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @keepomen, try this code `elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]")
for element in elements:
 print(element.text)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get that text excluding the `<b>` node text then you need to use the below XPath:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]
```

which will identify the div node and then by using `find_elements_by_xpath()` method, you can retrieve all the text from div node. Try the code below:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]") 
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

**Update:**

I suspect, the above method may not work and we may not be able to identify/get that data using the normal methods - in that case you need to use JavaScriptExecutor to get the data like below :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("file:///C:/NotBackedUp/SomeHTML.html")

xPath = "//div[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]"
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)
for element in elements:
    lenght = int(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes.length;", element));
    for i in range(1, lenght + 1, 1):
        try:
            data = str(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes["+str(i)+"].textContent;", element)).strip();
            if data != None and data != '':
                print data
        except:
            print "=> Can't print some data..."
```

As your site is written in some other language other than English, you may not able to print/get some data.

For getting specific child nodes data, you need to do like below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("file:///C:/NotBackedUp/SomeHTML.html")

xPath = "//div[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]"
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)
for element in elements:
    # For print b1 text
    b1Text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent", element);
    print b1Text

    # For printing b2 text
    b2Text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[6].textContent", element);
    print b2Text

print("=> Done...")
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: @keepomen, added code for getting `b1` or `b2` text. Check and let me know it is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Using Beautifulsoup:

Find the `div` with the `id = popover-34252127` inside the parent `div`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.your_url_here.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find("div", {"id": "popover-34252127"})
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_elements_by_xpath()` returns a webelement - the basic object selenium actually works with.
Your xpath ends with `/text()` - that will return you the text content of a node in an xml document - not an object selenium expects. So, just change it not to have that suffix - that will return the element itself, and get its (the element's) text by calling `.text` in Python:

```
dneyot=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]")
for element in dneyot:
    print("Период показов >3 дней", element.text)
```

Comment: Работает ;) It's the same locator you have used - if you want to get only the first `<b>` child node, then append it in the xpath - `//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]/b[1]`.

Comment: By the way, you are aware your current approach will **not** print _only_ the items which are with periods more than 3 days, right? I'm going after the print's content.

Answer (score 0):

`text()` returns text node, selenium doesn't know how to handle it, it can only handle `WebElement`s. You need to get the text for element with id "popover" and work with the returned text

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]")
for element in elements:
    lines = element.text.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        print("Период показов >3 дней", line)
```

Comment: dneyot=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'popover-')]").text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @keepomen should be `driver.find_element_by_xpath`

Comment: i need elementS (all)

Comment: @keepomen Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression to get dates:

```
import re

#...

rePeriod = '(.*)(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} - \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})(.*)'

dneyot = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[id^="popover-"]')
for spisok in dneyot:
    m = re.search(rePeriod, spisok.text)
    print("Период показов >3 дней", m.group(2))
```

Comment: `::node()` won't work with Selenium. It only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: @JeffC you're right Selenium not support `::node()`